# What does underlined line mean in idea analyze stack trace window?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using the Intellij Idea tool "Analyze Stack Trace or Thread Dump". It works fine and it is very useful. I want to know why Idea underlines some lines in the analyzed stack. Why is the method `runAndReset` underlined in the example:

[image: analyzed stack trace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so called **Try Blocks Highlighting** feature meaning that the highlighted calls occur inside the `try/catch/finally` block and can potentially throw an exception.

IntelliJ IDEA uses bold dotted underline style for such statements in the stacktrace.